# Vanilla Javascript. Change style of element when scrolling.

Tags: javascript, scroll, offset

If I had a simple header, styled in a fixed position, as per below. How (in vanilla JavaScript) could I change the colour when scrolling, say when you scroll down 200px (the height of the header). All the examples I can find on stackoverflow are for JQuery only.

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

 header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
   position: fixed;
 }
```

```html
<body>

    <header>
      <h1>This is the header I want to change</h1>
    </header>

 </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried `if(scrollTop === 200)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function runOnScroll() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 200) {
     var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
      h1.style.color = "green";
      }
 }; 
window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll);
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

 header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
   position: fixed;
 }
```

```html
<body>

    <header>
      <h1>This is the header I want to change</h1>
    </header>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This may lead you in the right direction:

```js
// external.js
var doc, bod, htm;
addEventListener('load', function(){
  doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
  addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    doc.querySelector('header').style.backgroundColor = htm.scrollTop > 199 ? 'blue' : 'red';
  });
});
```

```css
/* external.css */
body{
  height: 2000px;
}
header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>This is the header I want to change</h1>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```